# Merge two tables and chain id fields in order

Tags: sql, merge, union, row-number

I'm looking for a way to merge two tables (or more) and modify/order their numeric id. To put it simply here is what I want to do schematically :

Table example 1 :

| Id | Field |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | x |
| 1 | x |
| 5 | x |
| 3 | x |
| 2 | x |

Table example 2 :

| Id | Field |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | x |
| 3 | x |
| 5 | x |
| 2 | x |
| 4 | x |

Expected result (modify table 1 as 1-2-3-4-5 and table 2 as 6-7-8-9-10 THEN order both id by asc)

| Id | Field |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | x |
| 2 | x |
| 3 | x |
| 4 | x |
| 5 | x |
| 6 | x |
| 7 | x |
| 8 | x |
| 9 | x |
| 10 | x |

I was aiming for a **union tables** nested in a **select row_number() over (order by id)** but I don't really know how to modify table 2 as 6-7-8-9-10 before

Comment: if you do the `union` and then the `row_number` of the resulting table, you probably will get what you want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this example:

```
SELECT id, Field FROM t1
UNION ALL
SELECT (SELECT MAX(id) FROM t1) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS id, Field
FROM t2
ORDER BY id
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7e5eb92d79bc4bb4a8aeb4a15cb65819)